# SQL Query on 3 Tables Get Column from One and Use it for the Other

Tags: sql, multiple-tables

I have a table, `commission`, that is being called from a function. It is selected by `user_id` and it will have certain columns named `sale_product_id`. This column is tied to another table: `sale_product`, which has another column, `sale_id`. Now there is one last table, `sale` that has ids.

Currently, here is what I have:

```
SELECT
    c.amount
FROM 
    commission AS c, 
    sale_product AS sp,
    sale AS s
WHERE 
    c.user_id = '[id]' AND
    c.sale_product_id = sp.id AND
    s.is_paid = 1 AND 
    (s.upline_user_id = c.user_id OR sp.sale_id = s.id)
```

I should have returning 6 rows, but there are 21. What am I doing wrong?

OUTPUT expectation (if I do `SELECT c.* ...`):

```
id   |   sale_product  | user_id |   amount    |
#    |      466        |   3     |    3.99     |
#    |      123        |   3     |    2.99     |
```

What I am getting are duplicates (I think because the other tables see sale product id and do something funky)

```
id   |   sale_product  | user_id |   amount    |
#    |      466        |   3     |    3.99     |
#    |      123        |   3     |    2.99     |
#    |      466        |   3     |    3.99     |
#    |      123        |   3     |    2.99     |
#    |      466        |   3     |    3.99     |
```

### #    |      123        |   3     |    2.99     |

I have made some changes to the SQL and I'm *almost* done.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT c.id, c . * , s . * 
FROM 
commission AS c, sale_product AS sp, sale AS s
WHERE
sp.id = c.sale_product_id
AND s.id = sp.sale_id
AND s.is_paid =  '1'
AND sp.cron_executed =  '1'
AND s.upline_user_id = c.user_id
AND c.user_id =  '3'
```

When I do this query, particularly the `s.upline_user_id = c.user_id` line, it gives me EXACTLY 1 query. This is correct. When I **remove** that line, I get all 6 rows. This is *also* correct. However, when I try to do this:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT c.id, c . * , s . * 
FROM 
commission AS c, sale_product AS sp, sale AS s
WHERE
sp.id = c.sale_product_id
AND s.id = sp.sale_id
AND s.is_paid =  '1'
AND sp.cron_executed =  '1'
AND s.upline_user_id <> c.user_id
AND c.user_id =  '3'
```

I get a null result. How come? Even if I change the line to `s.upline_user_id <> '3'`, (which btw should give me 5 rows), gives me null.

Anyone?

Comment: Sample data and expected output would have been great. We can not just imagine your data.

Comment: MySQL. What seems to be happening is I want to use the tables from `commission` and they are repeating themselves to fill the other tables. I can't share the content as it would violate client / developer privileges.

Comment: If you meant the type, InnoDB on all 3 tables.

Comment: Show us the schema of your tables. You need to join columns you haven't shown us.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean 'show us the schema'. Can you elaborate? I'm sorry it's been a long while since I've had to deal with SQL statements.

Comment: A wild guess: change your last line to `(s.upline_user_id = c.user_id AND sp.sale_id = s.id)`.

Comment: I thought so too, but when I delete this I get more than 1,000 rows. Could this be fixed with a `INNER JOIN` ?

Comment: joins are inner by default.  Somewhere you aren't doing enough of "where tableA.column1 = tableB.column2:

Comment: If ALL the excess rows are duplicates, you could say "select DISTINCT.....", but that is otfen (not always) indicative of not having enough column matching.

Comment: Thank you @CindyH , I'll keep beating this down.

Comment: What are you deleting? Change the `OR` to an `AND`, don't delete anything.

Comment: Please do not use `DISTINCT`, that will silently remove rows whenever a user happens to buy the same amount of a product.

Comment: I don't want to delete anything. I want to get rows from either `sale.id = sale_product.sale_id` OR `commission.user_id = sale.upline_user_id` but the row of `sale_product.sale_id` must also be `commission.sale_product_id = sale_product.id`

Comment: I need to make the `commission.id` available only once. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your OR operator on the join is likely causing the duplicate data because both are being met. If you are using the OR as a fallback when the condition is not met, think about using a CASE statement instead, if possible. Test the existence of the most likely condition first, ELSE is your fallback.

```
AND CASE 
       WHEN (a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NOT NULL) 
         THEN (a = b) 
         ELSE (c = d) 
    END
```

If you are testing strings, test for NULLs and lengths of zero.

Hope it helps!